# Button on MediaView JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

How would I go about creating a button on my MediaView component, such as a play button in the centre of the video that disapears when clicked. I am working with FXML so if you could give me an answer using that it would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add one `Button` on top of the media player, by having both on a `StackPane`.

Then add a method to the button, so when it's clicked the button it's hidden and the video starts playing.

I'll add also a way to show again the button once the video ends, letting you start again.

This is the FXML:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
    <children>
        <StackPane>
           <children>
              <MediaView>
                  <mediaPlayer>
                      <MediaPlayer fx:id="mediaPlayer" autoPlay="false">
                          <media>
                              <Media source="http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv" />
                          </media>
                      </MediaPlayer>
                  </mediaPlayer>    
              </MediaView>
              <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#playAndHide" text="Play Video" />
           </children>
        </StackPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and this is the `Controller` class:

```
@FXML private Button button;
@FXML private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(()->button.setVisible(true));
}    

@FXML
public void playAndHide(ActionEvent event){
    button.setVisible(false);
    mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.ZERO);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```